# Animation sw for GA algorithms

Tags: c#, java, html, algorithm

I'm looking to program a Genetic Algorithm but need software for visual simulation/animation representation. What would be appropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetLogo is one possible answer but its not quite as good as what im looking for in simulation/animation terms.